# Why do we have to save instance of a profile when that profile is already created and saved?

Tags: python, django, user-profile

I am following a tutorial in Django and I have some problem understanding code below:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

# why do we need to save instance? 'Profile.objects.create' already created and save that for us
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

That means if a user create an account or sign up to the website, using signals a profile will be created automatically associated to that user.

The question is that why do we need to save the instance of the profile because `Profile.objects.create(user=instance)` has already **created** and **saved** that instance simultaneously.

Even if I omit the second block of above code it will still work fine:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

What am I missing here or I don't understand or is it that we don't need that second block? Please help me understand this and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take it up with the authors of that tutorial.

The reasoning behind this is not for creation, but for when you're updating. For example, you might do this to update an existing user and their profoile:

```
user = request.user
user.last_name = 'Smith'
user.profile.info_field = 'Some details'
user.save()
```

There, you've called `save` on the user, but without that second signal you haven't saved the linked profile. The signal is intended to ensure that when you call `user.save()`, the profile is also saved automatically.

But this isn't a pattern that I like at all, and don't recommend it. If you're changing an object, you are responsible for saving it - in the code above you should call `user.profile.save()` rather than relying on a signal.

Comment: Sir, like before I omitted the second signal created a new user and updated that user, everything works fine without second signal and link is maintained without any problem.

Comment: No-one said anything about maintaining a link. Why are you concerned about that?

Comment: Sorry sir, My English is not good. I don't know how to elaborate this. 
You said the reason behind second signal is not for creation but for when you're updating. 
Then I created and updated a new user without second signal, everything were working fine. I double checked the database and all was well. 
What I didn't understand here ?

Comment: But we're talking about updating the profile, not the user, as I show in that example. Without that signal, the `info_field` data on the profile will *not* be saved to the db.

Comment: yes sir. I updated both. 
I have two fields in profile respectively image and bio. I updated bio and image both. 
I mean without second signal I updated the profile and still changes were saved to the db.

Comment: Well, once again, if you don't have the signal then that profile will not be saved. If you think differently, please update your question with the exact code you used and the results you saw.

Comment: Thank you sir for dedicating your time. I really appreciate your answers, your insight and answers have always helped me. I believe I made some mistakes that I can't find.Thank you sir!

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have a question. Does the second signal "save_profile" have a bug? If I create a user, and I don't have a profile yet, the code instance.profile.save() will fail. The code shown by op assumes that the first signal "create_profile" always get executed first then follow by the second signal "save_profile". There is no order to signal, right? When I create a user and type user.save(),  which signal method will get executed first: "save_profile" or "create_profile"? The order of which signal get executed first matters.